# Do probability measures have to be the same if they agree on a generator of Borel $\sigma$–algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{K}\subset 2^\mathbb{R}$ is such that $\sigma(\mathcal{K})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be measures which agree on $\mathcal{K}$, i.e. $$\mu(A)=\nu(A)$$ for all $A\in\mathcal{K}.$ Do these measures necessarily have to be the same?

I am teaching myself in measure-theoretic probability and for now I can only prove  that the answer is yes, assuming $\mathcal{K}$ is a $\pi$-system. However, I do not know what to think when $\mathcal{K}$ is arbitrarily chosen. I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: A closely related question: [What is an example of a lambda-system that is not a sigma algebra?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8173/what-is-an-example-of-a-lambda-system-that-is-not-a-sigma-algebra)  This contains what is essentially did's example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** On the measurable space $(\Omega,2^\Omega)$ with $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$, consider $\mathcal K=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$, $\mu=\frac12(\delta_1+\delta_3)$ and $\nu=\frac12(\delta_2+\delta_4)$. Then $\sigma(\mathcal K)=2^\Omega$ and $\mu(A)=\frac12=\nu(A)$ for every $A$ in $\mathcal K$ but $\mu\ne\nu$.

**What is left to do:** To adapt this counterexample to $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$.

Comment: @Byron Sorry...

Comment: May the faster typist win! Ha ha...

Comment: @Byron Yes, this is one not-so-good aspect of the site. (But I left something to do for the OP...)

Comment: In fact, I have been familiar with examples such as yours or given by Nate Eldredge in his comment and what posed the major difficulty for me was exactly to notice that I simply have to _adapt_ them to the $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ case. Thank you for the sharpest hint I could get.
Just to make sure I am not mistaken: I simply define $\mathcal{K}=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}\smallsetminus \{1,2,3,4\})\cup \{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\}\}$ which, indeed, generates $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then the measures described by you agree on $\mathcal{K}$ but are not the same. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes. Note that $\{3,4\}$ may be omitted from $\mathcal K$ without changing the result.

Comment: @did Could you explain, why is $\mathcal{K}$ still a generator of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ then?

Comment: Because $\{3,4\}$ is the complement of the union of $\mathbb R\setminus\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{1,2\}$.

Answer (score 8):

In this context, it is useful to consider probability measures on a product space, say $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Let $\cal K$ be the collection of subsets generated by the projections onto the $x$ and $y$ axes.
Then $\cal K$ generates the Borel $\sigma$-field on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on 
$\cal K$ exactly when they have the same marginal distributions.

But of course, $\cal K$ is far from being closed under intersections and there are 
many *different* measures with the same marginals.

Comment: Indeed. +1. $ $