# Are Dynkin systems also $\pi$ systems?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a sample space.

A collection $\mathcal{D}$ of subsets of $\Omega$ is called a Dynkin sytem if

1. $\Omega \in \mathcal{D}$
2. $D \in \mathcal{D}$ implies $D^c \in \mathcal{D}$
3. $D_i \in \mathcal{D}$, $i \geq 1$, pairwise disjoint implies $\bigcup_i D_i \in \mathcal{D}$.

A collection $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets of $\Omega$ is called a $\pi$ system if it is closed under intersection.

Now it seems to be quite clear that not every $\pi$-system can be a Dynkin system. But what about the other way round? Is every Dynkin system also a $\pi$-system?

By 2. and 3. it follows that $\bigcap_i D_i = (\bigcup_i D_i^c)^c \in \mathcal{D}$ when $D_i \in \mathcal{D}$ and the $D_i^c$ are pairwise disjoint. But I am not sure first what this means for the $D_i$ and whether one can make some other conclusion?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8173/what-is-an-example-of-a-lambda-system-that-is-not-a-sigma-algebra) shows that a Dynkin system need not be a $\pi$-system.

Comment: Yes, but the example in the answer shows that the Dynkin system is not closed under intersections, so it is not a $\pi$-system.

Comment: I've got it. Thank you. :-)

Comment: A $\pi$-system is closed under *finite* intersections, not under *any* intersection.