# Is there a (non probability) example of a lambda-system that is not a sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Most the examples given here [What is an example of a lambda-system that is not a sigma algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8173/what-is-an-example-of-a-lambda-system-that-is-not-a-sigma-algebra)
 are probability examples.

Are there any non probability examples?