# Example of semi ring that is not semi algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

I know that every semi algebra is a semi ring but is the converse true?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Yes, thank you. Can this example also be used to show that not every ring is a algebra.

Comment: Another example is the family of finite subsets of an infinite set, it is also a ring which is not an algebra.

Comment: @Conifold, sorry to bother you. Do you have any example that answers my question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291052/is-there-a-non-probability-example-of-a-lambda-system-that-is-not-a-sigma-alge ?